# Why not output the first element array?

Tags: php

Why not output the first element array?

i use next code

```
$product_idn='123112$2313213';
$count_products=substr_count($product_idn,'$')+1;

$idn_products=explode('$',$product_idn);
$name_products='';
$s=0;
while($s<=$count_products){
$prod=$idn_products[$s];
$res10=mysql_query("..... WHERE `product_idn`='$prod'");
$i10=mysql_fetch_assoc($res10);
$name_products.=$i10['name'].', ';
$s++;
}
echo $name_products;
//give 2313213,,
```

Why not output the first element array ?

Comment: why don't you use `for(...)`?

Comment: i prefer foreach() for array loops, no counting needed

Comment: yes realized that foreach would be better right after commenting :D

Comment: Can you list the contents of the table you are querying, or if that is too large, how about something like: `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE product_idb IN('123112', '2313213')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
$product_idn='123112$2313213';

$idn_products=explode('$',$product_idn);
$name_products='';

foreach($idn_products as $val){
$res10=mysql_query("..... WHERE `product_idn`='$val'");
$i10=mysql_fetch_assoc($res10);
$name_products.=$i10['name'].', ';
}
echo $name_products;
```

Comment: Whilst this is arguably a cleaner way of looping in this case, can you actually see a problem with the original loop? Unless I'm just tired, it looks like it should work. I suspect that the reason Leo isn't seeing results is because the SQL query does not return a result for that product?

Comment: Yes, that's my conclusion as well.  There's just lots of little tweaks to the original code that could be applied, like $count_products=substr_count($product_idn,'$')+1; could just be $count_products=substr_count($product_idn,'$', 1);  Rather than write an essay, it's better just to post typical code.

Comment: well then @LeoLoki please give a bit more information what these variables are and what you want to get from the MySQL database..

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of unusual techniques being used in the original code.  My best guess at what I'd do, without really knowing the purpose of this code is:

```
$product_idn = '123112$2313213';

$idn_products = explode('$', $product_idn);

$name_products = '';
foreach($product_idn as $value) {
    $res10 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM ... WHERE `product_idn`='$value'");
    if ($res10) {
        $i10 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res10);
        $name_products .= $i10['name'].', ';
    }
}
$name_products = rtrim(', ', $name_products);
echo $name_products;
```

Comment: Sure, i had a mistake on the query... see ammendment.. needs to use $value in the query where criteria in my version.